# How can I delete the old cookies in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, cookies

In Google Chrome, there's only an option to delete the newest cookies. I want to delete the oldest ones. How can  I do that?

Comment: What I meant is that I want to keep the new cookies, but not the old ones. I have cookies from a year ago, I want to only delete those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to look for cookie manager software. You want one that will let you sort the cookies by creation date or modified date. Then you can just select all the cookies past a certain date and delete them.

For example, NirSoft [ChromeCookiesView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/chrome_cookies_view.html) looks like it has those features.

(I have used the NirSoft IECookiesView and liked it. The Chrome one should be similar.)

Answer (score 3):

I do not believe you can delete history easily without deleting the time since that period. See the link for a explanation of how Chrome stores cookies maybe you can go through the directories and delete the time period you want.

From [www.catonmat.net](http://www.catonmat.net/blog/clear-privacy-ie-firefox-opera-chrome-safari/):

> Google Chrome
>
> Chrome stores history, cookies, cache and bookmarks in various databases and directories 
>   in the per-user application data directory at C:\Users>>>\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data. The easiest way to get rid of all this data is just to erase everything there. Chrome creates this directory anew if it finds it missing.
>
> ```
> @echo off
>
> set ChromeDir=C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data
>
> del /q /s /f "%ChromeDir%"
> rd /s /q "%ChromeDir%"
> ```
>
> This simple batch script first deletes all files in %ChromeDir% directory via del command 
>   and then deletes the directory itself via rd command. The /q flag makes the del command 
>   quiet, the /s makes it delete files from all subdirectories, and /f forces it to delete 
>   read-only files, too. The /s flag to rd makes it delete all subdirectories and /q makes 
>   rd quiet.

Answer (score 0):

To delete all cookies in **Google Chrome**:

Click the **Wrench** on the top left.
Go to **Under the Hood**.
Click **Clear Browsing Data**.

Select one of the following options:

[image]

[image]

---

In response to the comment from the OP, there is no way to remove cookies by date. Although you can remove them by site.

And if you **must** delete them by date, you can open each individual cookie and check the date it was created.

Open up **Content Settings**

[image]

Open **All cookies and data**

[image]

Open up any website and open the individual cookie and do what you want with it.

[image]

Comment: What I meant is that I want to keep the new cookies, but not the old ones. I have cookies from a year ago, I want to only delete those.